# How to get array value from the other array in react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In this code I want the value in centreValues to come from some other array

```
    const centreValues=[
  {
    title:'Type',
    value:centreDetail.location_type
  },
  {
    title:'Address',
    value:centreDetail.address1+centreDetail.address2
  },
  {
    title:'City',
    value:centreDetail.city
  },
  {
    title:'State/Province',
    value:centreDetail.state
  },
  {
    title:'Postal/Zipcode',
    value:centreDetail.zip
  },
  {
    title:'Phone',
    value:centreDetail.phone
  },
]
```

my centreDetails is json like this:

```
centreDetails={
   location_type:'some Value',
   address1: 'some Value',
   address2:'some Value',
   ....
}
```

I want to bring these values in centreValues array.How could I do that?

Comment: Can you make a clearer explanation about : What your input is, what your current output is and what your desired output is

Comment: see edited version

Comment: Your code does what you explained you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

its a easy JS object and array scenario. According to your provided array it seems that you expect to have `centreDetail`. see my below example

```
const centreDetail = {
     location_type: "something",
    city: "something",
    state: "something",
    zip: "something",
    phone: "something",
}
```

now you can call the following above object in your array

```
const centreValues=[
  {
    title:'Type',
    value:centreDetail.location_type
  },

  {
    title:'City',
    value:centreDetail.city
  },
  {
    title:'State/Province',
    value:centreDetail.state
  },
  {
    title:'Postal/Zipcode',
    value:centreDetail.zip
  },
  {
    title:'Phone',
    value:centreDetail.phone
  },
]
```

EDIT: you added json in your question now. therefor, you need a loop. use `for` loop or `while` to go through the each index of array and added in your other array. you can also use `map` for that also

EDIT according to your comment. are you sure about that. see i typed this all in console. it seems to be working.

[image]

Comment: I am using the data like this only but the value is coming undefined

Comment: My structure is similar but I am getting values undefined in console

Comment: (13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {title: "Type", value: undefined}
1: {title: "Address", value: NaN}
2: {title: "City", value: undefined}
3: {title: "State/Province", value: undefined}
4: {title: "Postal/Zipcode", value: undefined}
5: {title: "Phone", value: undefined}
6: {title: "Fax", value: undefined}
7: {title: "Email", value: undefined}
8: {title: "President", value: undefined}
9: {title: "Secretary", value: undefined}
10: {title: "Treasurer", value: undefined}

Comment: @EshantBist can you try in console by copying your both arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve it :

```js
const centreDetails = {
   location_type:'my location',
   address1: 'an address',
   address2: 'another address',
   phone: '516546548',
   city: 'Wakanda'
}

const centreValues = Object.entries(centreDetails).map(([title, value]) => ({ title, value}))

console.log(centreValues)
```

You will have to convert your object into an array made out of pairs of key and values which is made using Object.entries()

Then you only have and create your desired structure using map on your array

---

EDIT
You can apply an additional filter function if you only want certain fields :

```js
const centreDetails = {
    location_type: 'my location',
    address1: 'an address',
    address2: 'another address',
    phone: '516546548',
    city: 'Wakanda'
}

const desiredValues = ["location_type", "address2", "city"]

const centreValues = Object.entries(centreDetails)
    .filter(([title, value]) => !!desiredValues.includes(title)) //Checks if the value exists
    .map(([title, value]) => ({ title, value}))

console.log(centreValues)
```

---

EDIT 2 :

If you want to have a different alias here's a way to do it :

```js
const centreDetails = {
    location_type: 'my location',
    address1: 'an address',
    address2: 'another address',
    phone: '516546548',
    city: 'Wakanda'
}

const desiredValues = {
    "location_type" : "location",
    "address2": "this guy\'s second address",
    "city": "Hey, he lives here !"
}

const centreValues = Object.entries(centreDetails)
    .filter(([title, value]) => desiredValues[title])
    .map(([title, value]) => ({ title : desiredValues[title], value}))

console.log(centreValues)
```

Comment: What if I want only some elements of this array?

Comment: You can filter out the array created, i'll update it with a new snippet

Comment: and suppose I want to change that title location_type as location what should I do for it

Comment: Alright, I'll update my answer in a few minutes, try listing everything you need in your question at once

Answer (score 0):

to get all values of centreDetail as object result

```
centreValues.map(x=>x.value.centreDetail)
```

To transfer to another array, manage the state like this:

```
centreValues.map(x=> this.setState({ centreDetailArray: [...this.state.centreDetailArray, x.value.centreDetail] })
```

Then you can get the result from state like this:

```
<View>  
  {this.state.centreDetailArray.map(x=><Text>{x}</Text>)}
</View>
```

Comment: This is not a React question ;)

Comment: It is written 'React Native' in your title

Comment: Its Basically a react question doesn't matter whether its react or react-native